# How to hide the radgrid filter header while still allowing filtering?

Tags: telerik, filtering, radgrid

I have a radgrid which allows filtering, but the filter strings come from external text boxes (so I can use autocomplete on them).

Is there a way to hide the radgrid's built in filter fields while still allowing filtering on the radgrid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just threw this on the page and it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function pageLoad(sender, args) {
      $find('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().hideFilterItem();
   }
</script>
```

Thanks to Vlad at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-hide-show-filter.aspx

Comment: Worked like a charm for us. We wanted client side filtering to work in our combobox which was in a header template without the default filter template rendering in between the header row and the content rows, which was costing us some real estate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is still a valid , but I had a similar issue, only thing is I did not want to show it at all. I turns out that adding 
IsFilterItemExpanded="false" in your MasterTableView also "hides" it:

i.e.